# Is it possible to add an IFERROR when combining ranges with curly brackets { }

Tags: google-sheets

For example, I want to query data from 12 sheets:

```
{query 1; query 2; query 3; query 4; query 5; ... }  and so on.
```

Some of these sheets might not exist yet. Say query 4 and query 5 fails, I still want it to be able to display data from query 1, query 2 and query 3. I was hoping to implement it like this:

```
{IFERROR(query 1, {}); IFERROR(query 2, {}); IFERROR(query 3, {})}
```

Where {} is an empty range. Or like this:

```
query({IFERROR('Sheet 1'!A1:B100, {}); IFERROR('Sheet 2'!A1:B100, {}) "select * where ...")
```

But I get an Array_Literal error when I do this.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Adding "" inside the {} Range. for example , if you have 6 rows that is returned then

```
{IFERROR(query 1, {"","","","","",""}); IFERROR(query 2, {"","","","","",""}); IFERROR(query 3, {"","","","","",""})}
```

Hope this could help!

Comment: Hell yeah this works! Thanks so much, I knew there was something for an empty set/range but I couldn't quite find it